# Unity "scrape away" effect

Tags: unity

I am trying to create a effect similar to what is described here [How can I let players "scrape away" one texture to reveal another?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/168874/how-can-i-let-players-scrape-away-one-texture-to-reveal-another/184525?noredirect=1#comment331003_184525)

I have tried working through this but am confused and hoping someone could provide more info or if there is another way of doing it. Essentially I need to use a laser effect to "burn" or scrape paint from a door to reveal a layer below. Or any object.

I have a object which I have applied the shader to, I can then apply my "rust" and "clean" texture. When I add the splatmap the "rust" texture shows, when I run the scene.. a mouse click then does nothing.

Comment: Can you tell us more why the answer to the question you linked to does not help you? What exactly confuses you about it? Why do you think that this method is unsuitable for your particular use-case so you are you looking for another way?

Comment: In its present form, we would typically close this question as a duplicate of the one you've linked. If you edit your question to elaborate on where specifically you're stuck in implementing the existing answer, or what special aspect of your use case requires a different solution as Philipp says, that would make it a jew question that can stand on its own, so we can keep it open for new answers.

Comment: We're going to need more detail than this in order to reproduce your problem. In particular, did you remember to add the script that does the scraping? It's not mentioned in your question. Walk us through every step — and I mean literally every single button click — that you took to try to incorporate this answer into a new, empty project. That will help us spot what's missing.

Comment: Have created the scrips in Unity, DotClick assigned to the main camera, and camera object added. The custom shader when then applied to the object. Texture was applied to the "clean" and "rust" components. At this point, the object will show with the rust layer. I then apply what i believe to be the SplatMap (UV looking) at this point the object reverts back to the  "clean" state, i have set the Splatmap to read/write then set to Read/Write.

Comment: The ratio of rust vs. clean for each pixel depends on the red-channel of the splat texture. 0 red means all clean and 255 red means all rust. How does the splat texture you assigned look?

Comment: The splat map I have, as i dont really understand them is essentially just the "normal" map. UV would be the best description. I think the issue here is not really understanding the splat texture and how to create it